# would it make sense to find a direct sum of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m \neq n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The elements of the resulting vector space would be sums of vectors with mismatched dimensions.  How can we add $(1, 2, 1)^T$ to $(-1, 2, -1, 5, -17)^T$ for example?  Can it be done?  What are the restrictions on direct sums, if any?

Comment: it makes sense if you embed them into a larger ambient space $\Bbb R^{m+n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The direct sum of two vector spaces $U$ and $V$, with $U\cap V=\emptyset $, is the set of all vectors of the form $u+v$, where $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.

Since the direct sum is defined in terms of the sum of vectors, they must lie in the same "type" of space. You can't simply sum a vector and a polynomial and expect the result to make sense. So, by extension, the dimension of both vectors must be the same.